# How to get out of a while-loop in c#

Tags: c#

Here I am trying to have the user enter "YES" to continue with the game but i'm stuck in the while-loop. This is also my first post so I don't the correct way to post ie. copy and paste? Also is there a indentation shortcut for Visual Studio? Thanks for helping.

```
using System;

namespace BIT_142_Major_Assignment_1 
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     int numGames = 0;
     String answer = "";
     Random rand = new Random();
     int Dice1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
     int Dice2 = rand.Next(1, 7);
     Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Andy’s Dice Game.");
     Console.WriteLine("Let’s start!");

        {
            while (true)
            {
                numGames++;


                Console.WriteLine("Dice 1: " + Dice1);
                Console.WriteLine("Dice 2: " + Dice2);

                Console.WriteLine("I got " + Dice1 + " and " + Dice2 + "!");
                if ((Dice1 + Dice2) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odds!");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?");
                    answer = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (answer == "YES")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The number of times the dice was thrown is: " + numGames);
                        Console.WriteLine("Nice Game!");
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank for playing, Come play again soon!");
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Why do you write `while(true)` if you don't mean it?? How about `while (answer == "YES")`. Initialize it to "YES", of course.. - In general a) try to avoid neeply nested structures and b) if you really really can't, you may have one of the very very rare case of using a `goto´. Only forward, please.

Comment: You throw the dice only 1x

Comment: is anwer really only "YES" or does it contain the return as well? If so, your test will always fail.

Comment: Dont use `goto` as @TaW suggested. If you find yourself using `goto` you are doing something wrong and there is definitely and absolutely a better way.

Comment: @pet: Nope, there are rare cases that will profit from a `goto`. They always are deeply nested loops and/or conditions. Here the best solution is obviously what I wrote... - And, yes it is unlikely that a newbie would run acroos them. I did maybe 2-3 times in the last couple of years.

Comment: @TaW maybe `goto` could work in this case, but such a game should not be written as a deeply nested loop - therefore the entire code shouldnt be as it is. Of course this is someone starting out but the point is to not suggest goto, rather than incensitivse good code that doesnt need to rely on an unreliable, old and obsecure function.

Comment: If you carfully re-read my comment(s) you will notice that I id not recommend either. But still: calling `goto` _unreliable, old and obsecure function_ is nonsense. It does have its uses but only for the advanced coders. - Other than that we agree.

Comment: I tried while (answer == "YES") an it resulted the same result

Comment: Switch from a `while` loop to a [do...while](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loop so the check is at the bottom.  Chase their response with [ToUpper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netcore-3.1) `Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()` so that your check will match no matter how the user types it in: `yes`, `Yes`, `YES`, `yEs`, etc.  As @Goodies pointed out, your dice are currently only rolled ONCE.  Move the `rand.Next()` calls to INSIDE the loop so that each time the game is played again you'll get a new roll.

Comment: As it's currently written, the user will only get asked if they want to play again if the sum of the dice was odd.  Probably not what you wanted...